# Can Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool be used with Nemo file browser in Cinnamon?

Tags: cinnamon, nautilus, nemo

In the past I used 
[Nautilus-Actions Configuration Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/nautilus-actions/)
 with Nautilus.

Can that be used with Nemo File manager (a fork of Nautilus originally)?

Comment: initially found on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/q/190535/47206)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer came to [the older once closed question now reopene](https://askubuntu.com/q/190535/47206)d.

Summing up what I have learned from the [main answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/190535/47206):

1. Nemo or Nautilus actions are similar in content  and purpose (namely, adding menu items) but vary with respect to the extension name. (In nautilus, newly created actions and menus will be stored on the disk as `.desktop` files, In nemo as `nemo_action` files.) They invoke certain commands including scripts (which are in this sense called nautilus or nemo scripts). Therefore, **nautilus scripts can be used if invoked by nemo_action files**, as they were nautilus actions, while **the latter can be adapted** for the purpose to fit Nemo.
2. **The `nautilus-actions` tool, a graphical editor for nautilus actions, will therefore not work with nemo** because it looks for `.desktop` files, not `.nemo_action` files.